How can I add the pattern to the entity ruler to identify Indian phone number?
import spacy

text = "This is a sample number +919999999999"

nlp = spacy.blank("en")


ruler = nlp.add_pipe("entity_ruler")
patterns = [
                {"label":"IND_PHONE_NUMBER","pattern":[{"ORTH":"+"},{"SHAPE":"dd"},{"SHAPE":"dddddddddd"}]}
            ]
ruler.add_patterns(patterns)

doc = nlp(text)

for ent in doc.ents:
    print (ent.text, ent.label_)

I have done the above code so that it can identify the Indian number but it is not giving any output.
